# Can I import java libraries in HP ALM without Microsoft Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: jvm, alm, hp-quality-center

I'm investigating ways of integrating different test tools with HP ALM. I would love to be able to execute java functionality as a part of this.

In the test-script pane of a VAPI-XP test, there is a button just below the *File* menu option. It shows/hides the browser panel. The browser panel has five tabbed panes: Library, Soap, Java, Function and Object. Here is a visual:

[image]

It looks very promising, and tutorials shows me that I actually can add java functionality to the execution of my tests here! There is a linked option for adding libraries/classes in the Test->References menu option, as shown here:

[image]

But when trying to reference java classes, I get this error message:

[image]

I had never heard of Microsoft Java Virtual Machine(MSJVM), and a quick search answered why that was. It was discontinued in 2003, and support ended in 2007. When installing HP ALM you can appearently choose to not install the old and outdated MSJVM, and my company has chosen to do this.

Re-installing the MSJVM is not an option, and I can't help but wonder if there is another way to reference java code in my tests? It seems unlikely that a big company like HP wouldn't update their functionality to be compliant with components that wasn't deprecated a whole decade ago. Especially since computer years are kind of like dog years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS JVM is discontinued and not supported. Refer HP ALM 11.52 readme and it indicates a known issue with usage of MS JVM with HP ALM and recommends to remove MS JVM (notes from Readme):

- Windows XP (SP3) with Internet Explorer 8: When connecting to ALM,
  Internet Explorer may crash. This is as a result of Microsoft Java
  Virtual Machine being installed on the client machine. The component
  does not integrate properly with Internet Explorer 8, and Microsoft
  recommends removing it. For more information, see
  http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/interoperability/java/faq.aspx
  Workaround: Remove msjava from the client machine. Alternatively,
  delete or rename the file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msjava.dll To remove
  msjava, use the Microsoft JVM Removal Tool described at:
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826878

Link for readme: https://almuniversityofminnesota.saas.hp.com/qcbin/Readme.htm

To get this issue resolved, log a HP support ticket with details on the problem and they should be able to give a quick patch for the issue or resolve this issue in a major patch Release.

HP ALM uses msjava.dll to attach class References of Java. So, workaround is wither to have msjava installed on your client or get this fixed from HP so that they would use Oracle Java JVM.